# How to make an entity reference field an editable field in views

Tags: views, entities

I have a view that displays [entity references](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference). Entity references are assigned via select list and are filtered by a seperate entity reference field.

I installed the [Editable Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/editableviews) module so that I can directly edit the field from the view.

Even though the admin user has all the right permissions set up, they are still only able to see the entity reference field displayed on the view, but not actually edit it. Is there a conflict between the two modules? Or is there some kind of extra setting that I am missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All I need to do was to change the format of the view from "Table" to "editable table" :/